# Moving Gift message form block from Cart to Checkout step 1

Tags: magento2, checkout, giftmessage

I'm trying to move the Gift Options block(gift message form) from the current Shopping cart page to the first step of the Checkout (Shipping). I need to place it right under Shipping Methods. I tried adding a GiftMessage module to my theme and within this modified the layout file checkout_index_index.xml to reference the checkout root block for Gift Message insertion, but it was of no use. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions" name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" template="cart/gift_options.phtml" cacheable="false">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: @maquina did you find solution?

Answer (score 8):

First of all, we need to understand how the Magento Gift Message works on Cart Page.

```
vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/templates/cart/gift_options.phtml
```

This file is our light. We will save a lot of time if we understand its logic.

`window.giftOptionsConfig`: this global variable used for config. We should recreate it on checkout.

Let's start to implement our custom logic. Create a new module, add following logic:

app/code/Vendor/CheckoutDemo/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CheckoutDemo/shipping</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!--Gift Options Cart-->
                                                            <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">gift_options</item>
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                                                    <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <!--End Gift Option-->
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gift.messages.data" template="Vendor_CheckoutDemo::gift_options.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

There are 3 notes:

-Shipping step will use our custom shipping html template. It's easier to add our custom region.

```
<item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CheckoutDemo/shipping</item>
        </item>
```

-Our Gift area: I copied the content from `vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml`.

```
<!--Gift Options Cart-->
    <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">gift_options</item>
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
            <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
        </item>
    </item>
<!--End Gift Option-->
```

-The Gift config

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gift.messages.data" template="Vendor_CheckoutDemo::gift_options.phtml"/>
```

Create app/code/Vendor/CheckoutDemo/view/frontend/templates/gift_options.phtml

```
<script>
    window.giftOptionsConfig = window.checkoutConfig.giftMessageConfig;
</script>
```

We use the `giftOptionsConfig` global variable because the gift message js logic will use it.

app/code/Vendor/CheckoutDemo/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="gift_message_checkout_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\CheckoutDemo\Model\GiftMessageConfigProvider\Proxy</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/CheckoutDemo/Model/GiftMessageConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CheckoutDemo\Model;

class GiftMessageConfigProvider extends \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\GiftMessageConfigProvider
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = parent::getConfig();
        return ['giftMessageConfig' => $config];
    }
}
```

Create the shipping html, copy the content from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` to our custom `app/code/Vendor/CheckoutDemo/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`. And, add our custom gift message region:

app/code/Vendor/CheckoutDemo/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

```
......
<div class="step-title" translate="'Gift Options'" data-role="title" />
<each args="getRegion('gift_options')" render="" />
......
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great. it's working fine.

Comment: can we add gift wrap option here as well?

Comment: @Kul gift wrap in Magento E-commerce version?

Comment: Yes. In commerce.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Anyway when I save the message it goes back to the cart page. This means that if the user has already filled other data, he has to start from scratch. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @Khoa TruongDinh I don't understand all the steps and I opened a new post for this exact same thing ( https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/346649/magento-2-4-2-gift-message-not-showing-up-on-front-end ) with a bounty of 50. Is there any chance you would consider making the steps easier to follow? Thank you and feel free to claim the bounty please. Or anyone really. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Try below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <block class="Magento\GiftMessage\Block\Cart\GiftOptions" name="checkout.cart.order.actions.gift_options" template="cart/gift_options.phtml" cacheable="false">
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
  </referenceContainer> 
 </body>
</page>
```

Earlier I have made one payment gateway extension in which I have rendered my custom template file in the payment section. I have also added that code here, Please add If I miss something. (Cirkle_Behalf) is Module name.

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
     <referenceContainer name="content">
      <block class="Cirkle\Behalf\Block\Behalf" name="behalf_popup" template="Cirkle_Behalf::behalf.phtml"/>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="renders" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!-- merge payment method renders here -->
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="behalf" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Cirkle_Behalf/js/view/payment/behalf</item>
                                                                    <item name="methods" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="behalf" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="isBillingAddressRequired" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>

                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
   </body>
</page>
```