# Magento 2.4.2 : Gift message not showing up on front end

Tags: porto-theme, giftmessage, magento2.4.2-p1

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Porto theme
```

I enabled Gift Messages in:

```
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Sales > Sales:
```

- Allow Gift Messages on Order Level
- Allow Gift Messages for Order Items

**It does not show up on the front end. What do I need to do to make this work?**

---

UPDATED on September 8th, 2021:

I read somewhere that this has been moved from the check-out page to the View Cart page in order to streamline the order process? I don't even see it in View Cart page and **we really really need to have it in the Check-out as we do deliveries and this is a must.** *Any solutions on how to achieve this will be appreciated.*

---

UPDATED on September 11th:

The solution suggested by Meet Shekhat (below) does not work for me.

**Any other possible solutions to this?**

---

I found this - would it help?

[Magento 2, display gift options in checkout page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161057/magento-2-display-gift-options-in-checkout-page)

---

I believe I found the original article that inspired Meet Shekhat:

[Moving Gift message form block from Cart to Checkout step 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184769/moving-gift-message-form-block-from-cart-to-checkout-step-1)

I was going to try those steps but it *gets confusing*. **Would anyone who understands it please write this out in:**

```
Step 1: do this
Step 2: do this
Step 3: do this 
etc.
```

---

**The bounty expires in 3 days. Would someone please have a working solution?** *This is critical for us.* I've spent days googling this and I can't seem to find a working solution. Thank you.

---

UPDATED September 13th, 2021:

*I checked the steps provided by Meet Shekhat 7 times. Everything is 100% correct* **but it does not work** = **the Comments field does not show anywhere!**

The link provided by Deep Shah:

[Moving Gift message form block from Cart to Checkout step 1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184769/moving-gift-message-form-block-from-cart-to-checkout-step-1)

is the one I have found previously but **cannot understand it properly**. **Would someone please re-write that posted answer and post here the steps from there?** *I will then gift you the bounty* provided it works. Thank you.

---

UPDATED on September 15th, 2021:

Just to be clear - the bounty expired but **I still haven't found a working solution.** I implemented both of the suggested solutions below but neither works for me = the box just doesn't appear anywhere!

Comment: Please try the below link: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/184769/moving-gift-message-form-block-from-cart-to-checkout-step-1 I hope it's work for you...

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I've added this link to my original post yesterday already but I also mentioned that the instructions are not clear to follow for me. Is there any way you could re-write them please in an easy to understand way? Such as Step 1: Create a file in path/file and put this in it. Step 2. Create another file in path/file and put that in it... Reading the other article for example: "There are 3 notes:
-Shipping step will use our custom shipping html template. It's easier to add our custom region." WHAT? What does that mean? Where does that go? I'm just lost.

Comment: Did you checked it on fresh magento 2.4.2-p1 instance? Is it working there?

Comment: @Rahul Barot I don't have a way to try this. We have a fresh Magento 2.4.2-p1 install with the Smartwave Porto theme and 9 extensions from Amasty installed by Amasty. Are you thinking it could be Amasty's extensions interfering with this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we need to understand how the Magento Gift Message works on Cart Page.

```
vendor/magento/module-gift-message/view/frontend/templates/cart/gift_options.phtml
```

This file is our light. We will save a lot of time if we understand its logic.

`window.giftOptionsConfig:` this global variable used for config. We should recreate it on checkout.

Create a new module, add following logic:

app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="shipping-step" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="shippingAddress" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_CheckoutGiftMessage/shipping</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <!--Gift Options Cart-->
                                                            <item name="giftOptionsCart" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">gift_options</item>
                                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/js/view/gift-message</item>
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message</item>
                                                                    <item name="formTemplate" xsi:type="string">Magento_GiftMessage/gift-message-form</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                            <!--End Gift Option-->
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </referenceBlock>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="gift.messages.data" template="Vendor_CheckoutGiftMessage::gift_options.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/view/frontend/templates/gift_options.phtml

```
<script>
    window.giftOptionsConfig = window.checkoutConfig.giftMessageConfig;
</script>
```

We use the `giftOptionsConfig` global variable because the gift message js logic will use it.

app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\CompositeConfigProvider">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="configProviders" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="gift_message_checkout_config_provider" xsi:type="object">Vendor\CheckoutGiftMessage\Model\GiftMessageConfigProvider\Proxy</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/Model/GiftMessageConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CheckoutGiftMessage\Model;

class GiftMessageConfigProvider extends \Magento\GiftMessage\Model\GiftMessageConfigProvider
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        $config = parent::getConfig();
        return ['giftMessageConfig' => $config];
    }
}
```

Create the shipping html, copy the content from `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html` to our custom `app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`. And, add our custom gift message region:

app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

```
......
<div class="step-title" translate="'Gift Options'" data-role="title" />
<each args="getRegion('gift_options')" render="" />
......
```

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: I have gone through all the steps, then deleted Cache and re-indexed but the Gift message still doesn't show on the front end. Did I do something wrong? The only thing I wasn't certain about is the very last bit = "And, add our custom gift message region:". Where exactly in the app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html file do I add this code? I just kind of put it in the middle of the file...

Comment: Please put code end of the file and please check.

Comment: That's exactly where it was (at the end of the file). I have just worked through all the steps backwards and double checked the file paths and also downloaded the files I previously uploaded to the server and then compared them with what you posted and everything is 100% correct but it doesn't work. I don't understand these things much but how is it meant to work if we didn't change/overwrite any of the existing code? Isn't it like if I made a file and put 'I'm the best' inside the file and then expected it to show up somewhere but it wouldn't be called up by anything?

Comment: If you don't mind can we connect on skype so i can properly understand your issue and help you.

Comment: Would TeamViewer work?

Comment: I will award the bounty to you because you tried to help even though I was not able to make it work at all in the end.

Comment: Apologies for let replay. I am okay with TeamViewer.

Comment: When are you free?

Comment: Today after sometimes.

Comment: Would now be good?

Comment: Can you please send me message on skype so I can notify properly and give you quick response.

Answer (score 0):

follow above solution to display Gift Options on Checkout page.

Step 1: Create file app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

Step 2: Create file  app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/view/frontend/templates/gift_options.phtml

Step 3: Create file app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/etc/frontend/di.xml

Step 4: Create file app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/Model/GiftMessageConfigProvider.php

Step 5: Create file app/code/Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

Note: In step 1 inside shippingAddress and inside children inside that create before-form item and in it's children add code which is inside shippingAddress item.

here you can change YourVendorName/YourModuleName instead of Vendor/CheckoutGiftMessage.

I hope this is help you out please go through steps and it's working fine.

Comment: @Allysin, I hope you like this steps.